# Несколько номеров в строке

Tags: jquery, плагин

Есть такой плагин Masked Input Plugin.

```
$("#phone").mask("+7(999) 999-9999");
```

Так задается маска для поля, где вводится один номер телефона. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было ввести несколько номеров?

Comment: сделай несколько инпутов с одним классом и вешай плагин на класс

Comment: Вводилось несколько номеров в один инпут?

Comment: @br3t да, несколько номеров

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так и планировал, но вдруг есть вариант какой хочу

Comment: @Player как это визуально должно выглядеть? какой смысл всё в один инпут пихать?

Comment: `$("#phone").mask("+7(999) 999-9999?,+7(999) 999-9999");`

Comment: @br3t то что нужно, спасибо